# Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError - Angular

Tags: angular

I have an array of data I loop wit `*ngFor`. I just want to check if a value is under or above 0, so I've made a checkPositive function. Here's the HTML code :

```
<div class="col-xs-4" [ngStyle]="{'color':color}">
    <span>{{checkPositive(contract.transactionAmount) | number: '1.2-2'}} {{contract.contractCurrency}}</span>
</div>
```

And the ts file

```
checkPositive(amount){
    if(amount > 0){
      this.color="blue";
      return amount;
    }
    else{
      this.color="red";
      return amount;
    }
  }
```

The result I get is that the first number has no color set.

[image]

and the console returns

`Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: 'blue'.`

I understand what the problem is, I just don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Can you provide reproduction in plunker?

Comment: It is actually complicated because i loop through data, But everything is here

Comment: The main problem here is that your checkPositive method is executed after ngStyle binding has been applied and inside checkPositive method you have side effect. https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#no-visible-side-effects

Comment: Sure, that's exactly what the problem is, however I can't seem to find a solution

Comment: `[ngStyle]="{ color: contract.transactionAmount ? 'blue' : 'red' }` and remove `this.color` inside checkPositive  method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using same component property for all the entry in your list.

Just try to do this

```
<div class="col-xs-4" [ngStyle]="{'color': contract.transactionAmount > 0 ? 'blue':'red'}">
    <span>{{ contract.transactionAmount | number: '1.2-2'}} {{contract.contractCurrency}}</span>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="col-xs-4" [style.color]="contract.transactionAmount > 0 ? 'blue':'red'">
```